# How to get body response in Interception?

Tags: angular, angular7

I use last Angular and need to get body request in interception here:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
            return throwError(err);
        }))
```

I tried to to that like:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
    .map((res: Response) => {
       if (res.result.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
       }

      return res;
    })
catchError(err => {
   return throwError(err);
}));
```

But it does not work for me

Comment: What is 'not work', what did you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `map` use `tap`, to get response and do some operations related to it, with `tap` you do not need to return smth.

```
   return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        if (response instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log(response);       
        }
      }, e => {
         console.log(e);
      })
   )
```

Comment: How to import tap, from rxjs?

Comment: import { tap } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';

Comment: Need I `response.json()`? to check if exist property?

Comment: But I need to check propery but `HttpResponse` does not have this property, my own like: `if (response['my']) {}`

Comment: you can check your property by accessing to `response.body['my']`, if your property isn't nested